# Unable to "yum install" on Oracle Linux 7 machine

Tags: linux, software-installation, yum, dns, oracle-linux

I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: 
[Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: yum.oracle.com; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from ol7_latest: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: 
[Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: yum.oracle.com; Unknown error"
```

Not sure what exactly this means. Can someone please give me pointers?

Comment: It seems you have problem with dns resolution. You can test it by running the "host google.com" command. It makes a dns query to the dns server defined in /etc/resolv.conf. If this command did not return an ip adress, you may try to change dns servers defined in /etc/resolv.conf. You can use OpenDNS service's dns server which are 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220

Answer (score 0):

That error means what it says on it's face - `Could not resolve host: yum.oracle.com`. Your machine can't 'see' yum.oracle.com because it can't find a DNS entry for that host. Try `host -v yum.oracle.com` to see if you can get more detailed error information.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for those who came here looking for a solution, the problem is that the machine cannot resolve Fully Qualified Domain Names (such as yum.oracle.com) to IP addresses.

To solve this, it is necessary to enter at least one DNS server into `/etc/resolve.conf`. One can use either 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220 (OpenDNS's DNS servers), 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 (Google's DNS servers), or the DNS servers specified by your ISP.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error when installing the vagrant box with Oracle Database from https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-projects. To workaround the problem here's what I did.
Login to vagrant box:

```
vagrant ssh
```

Become root:

```
sudo su -
```

Add nameserver `8.8.8.8` in `/etc/resolve.conf`.

```
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

From the vagrant box directory, provision the vm:

```
vagrant provision
```

Comment: Provisioning a DNS server for something intended to to connect to other hosts by name is not a "workaround".

Answer (score -2):

restart docker service it solved the issue for me

```
service restart docker
```

Comment: Where is docker involved in the question?